# How to keep highlighted text in WinRT/UWP RichEditBox on focus lost?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, uwp, windows-10

I'm working with a `RichEditBox` and I'm implementing some options to let the user edit a text with some formatting.

The problem is that every time the control *loses focus*, the highlight selection is hidden, even though the selection *remains active* and I can actually work on it.

Here's the `Template` I'm using, as you can see I've already removed all the `VisualState`s but that didn't solve the issue.

```
<Style TargetType="RichEditBox" x:Key="CustomRtfEditBoxStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RichEditBox">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="UnFocused" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                ...
```

Now, I guess that's not the problem, and the selection is managed somewhere in the internal code of the control.

**Note:** I *can't* actually use the [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25122775/keep-selection-visual-in-richeditbox-on-unfocus) to manually set the selection background color when the focus is lost and gained, as the text is exported/loaded as rich text and I can't mess the user settings. I need a way to do this without actually changing the formatted text.

I noted that the `RichEditBox` class is not `sealed`, so I was wondering if it was possible to override some behavior or do something to fix this issue, but I wouldn't know where to start.
I know that on WPF there are some other workaround to solve this issue (like the handy property to just keep the highlight when the focus is lost), but that isn't present on UWP.

Do you have any idea on how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there's not an easy/built-in way to accomplish this, so I've used this workaround:

```
EditBox.PreventKeyboardDisplayOnProgrammaticFocus = true;
EditBox.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
```

Calling the `Focus` method after setting the `PreventKeyboardDisplayOnProgrammaticFocus` property makes the text highlighted again without showing the virtual keyboard again.

This method makes the highlight color "flash" for a fraction of a second (after the control loses focus, until it gains it again, depending on how fast that `Focus` method is called), but it's not so annoying, and it fixes the issue for now.

Comment: Here is another workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37524488/uwp-show-textbox-text-highlight-while-textbox-is-out-of-focus